# How to show a block on pages with a path like '/member/*' but not 'member/*/likes'?

Tags: blocks

I want to show a block on a member's profile page (`member/*`) but not on `member/*/likes`.

It doesn't seem I can do this without PHP in the block settings, does it?

Answer (score 2):

Try restricting visibility to this URI:

```
member/*/
```

(trailing slash!)

Alternatively, you can download the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module and position the block using a new context, and negate the `member/*/likes` path in your context configuration.

Comment: I had tried member/*/ but then it wouldn't show on a member/user123 page

Comment: Grab the Context module - it'll do what you're after easily enough!

Answer (score 0):

There **is a way** to answer your question ***without PHP in the block settings***  (as in your question): you can use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module for this (assuming your question is about D7). Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on your pages with a path that **starts with** "`members/`", but not on those pages that have a path **ending with** "`/likes`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_show_on_selected_member_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on selected member pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "members\/",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "\/likes",
              "operation" : "ends"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

Also, if you'd replace the 2nd Rules Condition in the above Rules Component with something using an appropriate regular expression, you could even further refine it, to check for something like "`members/uid/likes`", whereas `uid` corresponds with some user's uid, and so that the block would be shown anyway on pages with a path like "`members/with/lots/of/likes`".